# Converting JS object to different order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have JS object like this one:

```js
const networkTree = [
  {
    id: 10,
    hasChildren: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: 9,
        hasChildren: true,
        children: [
          {
            id: 7,
            hasChildren: true,
            children: [
              {
                id: 5,
                hasChildren: false,
                children: [],
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                hasChildren: false,
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            hasChildren: true,
            children: [
              {
                id: 3,
                hasChildren: false,
                children: [],
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                hasChildren: false,
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        hasChildren: true,
        children: [
          {
            id: 1,
            hasChildren: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 11,
            hasChildren: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have to convert it with a function takes input js object like above to this order:

```js
const myTreeData = [
  {
    name: 'Top Level',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Level 2: A',
      },
      {
        name: 'Level 2: B',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I am stucked at this point:

```js
const convertTree = (array) => (
    treeDatas[];
    treeData[];
   for(i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
     treeDatas.push(array[i]);
     treeData[i].name.push(array[i].id);
   }
   
);
```

If input networkTree[0].id is 15, myTreeData[0].name should be 15. I want to use id's as names on converted object. I don't need hasChildren boolean value. I will use converted object format with react-ds3-component. If you need more information about converted object format please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-tree

Comment: Your original data has no `name` attribute, so I'm struggling to understand the relation between the two shapes you're showing. Can you edit your post to also show what, if you did this manually (for a small tree), the resulting data would _actually_ look like?

Comment: I need to take value of id's and use them as name value. I mean if id is 12, on converted object related name will be 12.

Comment: Don't tell me that, tell everyone, by [editing your post as per the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). Adding text and code that lets people understand what you need as clearly as possible will get you the best answers, or the most appropriate "someone already asked this in the past, but with different terms so you probably wouldn't have found it" link to a previous post here on SO.

Comment: Input and output in the question are still unrelated. Input has `id` values 1, 2, ..., 11. Output has 'Top Level', 'Level 2: A' and 'Level 2: B'. What is the connection? Where do the words "Top Level", "Level" come from, where does the number 2 come from, where do "A" and "B" come from. Where did the input value 1 go to? What about all the other input values?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to rename id to name and remove hasChildren? Then you can use this recursive function.

```
const convertTree = (tree) =>
  tree.map((node) => ({
    name: node.id,
    children: convertTree(node.children)
}))
```

It's the same as this function, just less verbal.

```
const convertTree = (tree) => {
    return tree.map((node) => {
      return {
        name: node.id,
        children: convertTree(node.children)
      }
    })
  }
```